# Finding the function approximated by a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

If I have a feed-forward multilayer perceptron with sigmoid activation function, which is trained and has known weights, how can I find the equation of the curve that is approximated by the network (the curve that separates between 2 types of data)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there is no closed form solution for the input points where your NN output is 0.5 (or 0, in case of -1/1 instead of 0/1).

What is usually done for visualization in low-dimensional input space is gridding up the input space and computing the contours of the NN output. (The contours are smooth estimate of what the NN response surface looks like.)

In MATLAB, one would do

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(linspace(-1,1), linspace(-1,1));
contour(f(X,Y))
```

where `f` is your trained NN, and assuming [-1,1] x [-1,1] space.